# Qt create and QLabel, why is there an error?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I'm using `Qt creator 2.0.1`, and when entering this line:

`#include <QLabel>`

I get the following error:

`QLabel: No such file or directory`

Why is that? And, how can I include a label in this case?

**UPDATE**

@maverik showed me how to solve the `QLabel` error, but I'm now getting this error:

[image]

The program I'm trying to run is:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
QCoreApplication myapp(argc, argv);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello");
label->show();
return myapp.exec(); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use

> QApplication

Rather than

> QCoreApplication

.

from the QCoreApplication docs:

> The QCoreApplication class provides an
>   event loop for console Qt
>   applications. This class is used by
>   non-GUI applications to provide their
>   event loop. For non-GUI application
>   that uses Qt, there should be exactly
>   one QCoreApplication object. For GUI
>   applications, see QApplication.

Then Include the relevant headers, and it will compile just fine.
QCoreApplication is for non-Gui applications (Console).

Comment: yes, maybe original poster has used Qt Creator to generate default console application and added QLabel there ( this why project file would have QT -= gui defined ). In that case he should use the "Qt Gui application"-option to generate default GUI application from creator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do that I get `QApplication: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

Check that your Qt project -file contains

```
QT += gui
CONFIG += qt
```

and does not contain

```
QT -= gui
```

I think this causes the linking problem. Also I think

```
#include <QLabel>
```

... should be enough if project file is correct.

Comment: This is probably the preferred answer to Maverik's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do that, I get a console window mentioning: `QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used`, and the second line `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate.....`, and the `.exe` file thus stops working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I think this removed the `QLabel` issue. But, I get new errors. Check my updated post of the error and the code I'm trying to run.

Comment: In what way you build the project? Do you use makefile or qmake? The problem seems to be while linking. You should link with the Qt libraries such as qtgui and qtcore. The best way to do this is to use qmake.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found where the issue is.

Since I'm using `Qt Creator`, and when creating a new project, I was choosing `Qt Console Application` instead of `Qt Gui Application`.

Comment: This was what @deo was getting at so you should really accept that answer (@soulSurfer2010 explains the subsequent problem creating a `QWidget`).

Answer (score 0):

QLabel Class
The QLabel widget provides a text or image display. More...

Header: #include 
qmake:  QT += widgets
Inherits:   QFrame
List of all members, including inherited members
Obsolete members

*** Simply add 
QT += widgets
to the .pro